# How to pass the values of multiple checkboxes checked value using JQuery to a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/qg8JG/)

```
 $('.myBox  input:checkbox').change(function(){
  var tempValue='';
tempValue=$('.myBox  input:checkbox:checked').map(function(n){  //map all the checked value to tempValue with `,` seperated
            return  this.value;
   }).get().join(',');

   $('#display').html(tempValue);
})
```

What is the best way to add the values of the checked checkboxes to a URL on the same page?

Obviously I cannot add `<div id="display"></div>` inside the URL.

Ideally I would like to display a static link at the bottom of the page which would have a dynamic Javascript variable if the checkboxes are checked.

Thank you.

Sasha.

Comment: What do you mean by pass a checked value to URL?

Comment: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.location.href` and k it like

```
var url=window.location.href+'?q='+tempValue;
// you can redirect the above url
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/J4D8B/)**

Try this to `add url` in `link`,

**HTML**

```
<a id="link"></a>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var href = '#';
var text = '';
if (tempValue) {
    text = 'Click me';
    href = 'http://example.com?q=' + tempValue;
}
$('#link').text(text).attr('href', href);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/J4D8B/1/)**

Comment: I don't need a redirect. Just a link at the bottom of that page that would dynamically change.

Comment: Thank you Rohan. Ideally I would like to display a static link at the bottom of the page that would have a dynamic Javascript variable if the checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to pass it to a link on the page. If so, something like this:

```
$('.myBox  input:checkbox').change(function(){
  var tempValue='';
  tempValue=$('.myBox  input:checkbox:checked').map(function(n){  //map all the checked value to tempValue with `,` seperated
        return  this.value;
   }).get().join(',');

   $("a#linkyouwantotchange").attr('href', 'http://yourlink.com/?query='+tempvalue+'');
});
```